# Why is VS Code making me use "option + click" to open editor links instead of "cmd + click" on macOS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

My VS Code recently started to invert the system shortcuts from command to option.
As you can see here, the option to open a link is now option+click when it was cmd+click.
[image]

And the keybindings for open link is set as `system`
[image]

This made me think that the mac shortcuts (the system) should have changed.. but all the mac shortcuts are still using command, as shown in this setting:
[image]

I'm very confused, as I don't know what caused this and how to revert it back.
I tried working with this, but it's really annoying!

How can I revert this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What modifier is used for opening links is defined to not conflict with [whatever modifier you have chosen for working with multiple cursors](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multicursor-modifier). When you have set `editor.multiCursorModifier` to `"alt"`, you get <kbd>cmd + click</kbd> for clicking links, and if you set `editor.multiCursorModifier` to `"ctrlCmd"`, then you get <kbd>option + click</kbd>.

[The docs for the multi-cursor modifier](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multicursor-modifier) support this:

> The Go to Definition and Open Link gestures will also respect this setting and adapt such that they do not conflict.

The description text for the `editor.multiCursorModifier` setting also says something to that effect.

The default value of `editor.multiCursorModifier` is `"alt"`, so I'm guessing you changed it to `"ctrlCmd"`.

You can cross-check with the source code too: The relevant code is in [src/vs/editor/contrib/links/browser/links.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/contrib/links/browser/links.ts). The string constants you see ("Follow link" and "option + click") are in the `getHoverMessage` function, where you can see that the choice of whether <kbd>option</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd> depends on a parameter named `useMetaKey`. The only caller of `getHoverMessage` is `_getOptions`- a private static function property of the `LinkOccurrence` class. `_getOptions` is used in its public, static `decoration` function property, and `activate` and `deactivate` instance function properties, which all just pass along `useMetaKey` parameters of their own. If you look for usages of the `LinkOccurrence` class, you'll see those functions used in the following places: `updateDecorations`, `_onEditorMouseMove`, and `cleanUpActiveLinkDecoration`, in each of which where `useMetaKey = (this.editor.getOption(EditorOption.multiCursorModifier) === 'altKey');`.

Comment: Lifesaver! I had a toggleMultiCursorModifier binding set that I probably pressed and changed that from cmd to option! Thank you very much!